# Navigation in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have "login.html" and "Main.html" two pages in my app. After successful validation in "login.html" Page, then it is navigating to "Main.html".

Here I am facing the problem;

once the "main.html" page has landed from login page, If I click the "Back" button in browser it is navigating back to "login.html" page. Here I don't want my app to navigate back to Login page without proper sign out. Please suggest any the secure ways to solve this issue in Angular JS.

Thanks in advance !.

Comment: use `session or localstorage`. Once user login successfully, store users' id or details. then while navigating, check if anything is there is localstorage. If yes then don't redirect to login page.

Comment: User can hack the session or local storage through developer tool.
Any other suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I know that. for the there should be proper authentication from both Server and Client side. you can use jwt tokens(for example). Without storing in localstorage or session storage, you wont be able to achieve what you want. Because there is no way, browser will keep track without them.

Comment: Use jwt token to generate a token then use this token to know if the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) { 
  if(clientSideValidationFails) { 
    if(serverSideValidaionFails) {
    }
  }
})
```

Just set `hasLoggedIn` state in your `localStorage` once user logs in.

Comment: local/session storage can be edible in developer tool. So this will not be secured way.

Comment: Bring  server side for validation then.

Comment: If you see from developer tool, then the entire html content can be changed by typing JavaScript directly in the console, even a new angularjs screen itself can be introduced, which was originally not part your application, which is unfortunate